# Brakes squeaking, front or rear?

Tags: brakes

Had my pads replaced 3 days ago with some high end ones.

Today, when braking to a stand still i notice some squeaking. It only makes a squeaking noise toward the end of braking just before coming to a stop.

Discs are new, been done 7 months ago.

Can't tell if it's from the front or back, how is the best way to tell ?

The rears are drums and were squeaking 7 months ago so I got them cleaned and lubricated and have been fine ever since.

I'm hoping it's just the new pads need to be bedded to the older discs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right about new pads. High end new pads, usually come with a little packet of lube . But, if you didn't get any or put any on the new pads, they probably will squeek a little for awhile until glazed over from friction.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to tell if it's front or back is to apply only the front or back brakes.  You can apply just the back brakes with your emergency brake lever.  If you hear the noise, it's in the back.  If not, it's the front.  Note:  If your car has disc brakes in the back, this won't work.